# How to preserve whitespace when getting text in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put text in a variable that preserves the whitespace. First, I receive my text from my database. This is how the text appears on the page as I used the function `nl2br()` to preserve the enters:

```
    random text.
    more random text.
```

I want to get this text in a variable while preserving the whitespace. Because the tags were wrapped in a div tag, what I tried was this:

```
var body = $("div").text();
```

However, when I console.log var body, the text's space isn't preserved and it comes out like this, without the newline preservation:

```
random text.    more random text.
```

Is there any way to preserve the whitespace when using variables to get the text of an element?

Comment: can you create a snippet to demonstrate the issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **.html** instead of .text.

```
$("div").html();
```

This will give you the html with br tags. Now you can replace them with new line and save into database.